# Android Content Provider Identical URI's not matching

Tags: android, uri, android-contentprovider

Am I misunderstanding something here? I'm trying to implement a ContentProvider in Android and for some reason the calling URI is not being matched.
In my ContentProvider I define the following:

```
private static final int GET_COURSES = 100;
public static final Uri COURSES_URI = Uri.withAppendedPath(CONTENT_URI, CourseTable.NAME);
private static final UriMatcher matcher = new UriMatcher(UriMatcher.NO_MATCH);
static 
{
    matcher.addURI(AUTHORITY, COURSES_URI.toString(), GET_COURSES);
}
```

Then, in my query call:

```
public Cursor query(Uri uri, ...)
{
    int type = matcher.match(uri);
    .
    .
```

Here, type is always -1... In the debug window I've viewed both the passing in uri and COURSES_URI and the string representations are identical...

Any suggestions?

Thanks

Update:

I call the Content Provider using:

```
new CursorLoader(this, CoursesProvider.COURSES_URI, null, null, null, null);
```

... this is boggling my mind... just got uri.equals(COURSES_URI) == true, so something must be incorrect in the UriMatcher

Answer (score 1):

Problem solved... 
The initial problem was that COURSES_URI also contained the AUTHORITY path:

```
private static final Uri CONTENT_URI = Uri.parse("content://" + AUTHORITY + "/" + DBManager.DB_NAME);
private static final Uri COURSES_URI = Uri.withAppendedPath(CONTENT_URI, CourseTable.NAME);
```

In the `matcher.AddURI(authority,path,code)` method the authority portion of path should be removed.

This can be obtained using `COURSES_URI.getPath().substring(1)` (substring to remove the leading '/' returned by getPath())